# matplotlib plotting dates - huge scribble mess

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am attempting to chart some stock info on matplotlib from a csv file

i put data from each column into a list, so date is one list, price is another and so on

when i plot price as a function of time, instead of getting a regular stock chart, it gives me a huge mess of squiggly lines everywhere

ive googled some examples and the solutions are above and beyond what i need and i cannot differentiate which part is just simply plotting date on the x axis

```
date = ['Jan 24, 2018', 'Jan 23, 2018', 'Jan 23, 2018']
price = [28.14, 29.01, 28.75]
plt.plot(date, price)
plt.show()
```

the code above is essentially how ive got it

can someone perhaps show me a simple example or link me a good matplotlib tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `Jan 23, 2018` twice in your `date` list. Did you mean to plot separate dates? Here is a modified example that seems to work just fine:

```
date = ['Jan 24, 2018', 'Jan 25, 2018', 'Jan 26, 2018']
price = [28.14, 29.01, 28.75]
plt.plot(date, price)
plt.show()
```

[image]

`matplotlib` will order the string values in `date` alphabetically. This is what is causing the values to appear scrambled. It would be a good idea to convert the strings to `datetime` objects before plotting them.